# Ember promise aware headers in Adapter

Tags: ember.js, promise, async-await, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Looking for a way to set header in Ember ADAPTER LATER with the value returned from an async call.

Trying to set the idToken returend from Amplify's `Auth.currentSession()`, which is a promise function which internally handles refreshing the token on expiration.

Something like this to await the response -

```
headers: computed(async function() {
        return {
          'Authorization': await Auth.currentSession().getIdToken();
        };
      })
```

.

.

I see that we can't make a promise aware computed property too for headers.

Also I am not looking for a solution using ember-simple-auth / ember-cognito or any other addons,
I need to achieve this just with plain amplify library and Ember adapters header .

Comment: Is this something you are looking for? https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_headers-customization making the header tracked getter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GokulKathirvel ✌️.
Hope tracked properties are the new computed properties way, as we are still in 2.15v, not familiar with annotations. Though it should be the same behaviour I think.
.
.


I could go with your solution if the value to be set in headers will be updated on an interval inside a service and I can compute/track the headers value based on that service attribute.

But for me the scenario is, whenever the headers in adapters is called, only at that moment I'll be making an asynchronous call to get the value and set in headers.

Comment: I'm not a user of Ember Data. However, you'll need to access the header for each server request, right? If so, can you make the `getIdToken` async call beforehand? however, accessing this async call on every request seems an overhead.

Comment: It needs to be asynchronously called every-time to get valid idToken ( if expired retrieving a new idToken with refreshToken in hand which is Amplify library behaviour anyway). Right now Yes that's how it's done like you said. Before making the call via Ember Data the token will be gathered beforehand and set via either `adapterFor` or  `snapshot.adapter.option` at routes/components layer. But I need to refactor them all and move it to one place inside the adapter layer itself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to override the adapter's `ajax` method.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    async ajax(...args) {
        // Store the parent call, so it can be called after getting the current session.
        const _super = this._super.bind(this);

        // Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with how you're accessing amplify
        const headers = await amplify.currentSession();

        this.set('headers', {
            'Authentication': headers.auth
        });

        return _super(...args);
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this & it seems to work exactly to my need. Did few tweaks to get the actual adapter's headers attributes first and then set other async one on top of it inside ajax. Thanks a ton man , just brilliant ✌️ !!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for newer versions (currently 3.21)

```js
export default class ApplicationAdapter extends RESTAdapter {
  @inject auth //my own auth service

  ajax(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this._getHeaders().then((headers) => {
        this.set('headers', headers);
        super.ajax(...args).then(resolve, reject);
      });
    })
  }

  async _getHeaders() {
    const token = await this.auth.token();
    return {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as well, not just code.